# B+ Tree structure with buckets (Begginer question)

Tags: index, database-theory

I am enrolled in a course and I am confused about few concepts in the structure of the B+Tree. I know what it does and what's the difference between it and BTree, but I got a bit conflicted when I saw 2 different examples:

1-B+Tree with buckets at the end:
[image]

2-B+Tree without buckets at the end:
[image]

Example 2 is the most popular example I noticed on the web.
My instructor told me that in example 2 the pointers of the leaves can point to buckets too, but wait a second it would be the same as the first example but with the last pointer to the left going to the next leaf.

Question: Is it mandatory for a b+tree leaf to have a pointer towards the next leaf?

My instructor told me to make it easier on myself to assume the bucket as a leaf that has a pointer towards the next bucket. It's better not to understand something on understanding something using a wrong way.

There's this clash inside me about the B+tree structure. Is there more than one structure for a b+tree?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not *mandatory* for a b+tree leaf to have a pointer towards the next leaf, but it is a widely used optimization to allow efficient scanning of value ranges, such as, in the context of relational databases, supporting `WHERE field BETWEEN x AND y` or `WHERE field > x` predicates. Frequently you see a leaf pointing to both *next* and *previous* leaves, supporting bidirectional scanning as well (for `WHERE field < x`). Apart from the search predicate support, it may also be useful for record ordering and aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually no big difference at all. A direct pointer link shortcut is completely optional. If you don't use any shortcuts, the jump to the next link takes some 3 or 4 pointers. If the algorithm uses a lot of horizonal jumps, it saves time; if not, you waste some extra resource.